# How to loop through a matrix and change certain elements?

Tags: r

My code at the moment is as follows

```
for(i in 1:3500){
  if ((matrix$column[i] == 'yes')|((matrix$column[i] == 'no'))){
    matrix$contact[i] = 'maybe'

  }
}
```

Basically, if an element is equal to either 'yes' or 'no', I would like to change it to 'maybe'.
The error I'm currently getting is

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = "maybe") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Try `mat[mat %in% c('yes', 'no')] <- 'maybe'`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the array or vector that you are trying to change is a Factor type and it has no level as `maybe` .

If you want to add or update your `factor` variable, first you need to change it to `character` type. You should do it before for loop. You can use `as.character(yourfactorvariable)` method to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a loop. Instead you can just use `apply`:

Some data:

```
mtx <- matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = 4)
y <- c("yes", "no", "other")
set.seed(123)
mtx <- apply(mtx, 2, function(x) sample(y, 8, replace = T)); mtx
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "other" "other" "other" "other"
[2,] "other" "yes"   "other" "no"   
[3,] "other" "no"    "yes"   "yes"  
[4,] "no"    "no"    "yes"   "no"   
[5,] "other" "yes"   "yes"   "other"
[6,] "no"    "no"    "yes"   "no"   
[7,] "no"    "other" "other" "yes"  
[8,] "no"    "yes"   "no"    "other"
```

And this is how you do the transform:

```
apply(mtx, 2, function(x) ifelse(x=="yes"|x=="no", "maybe", x))
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   
[1,] "other" "other" "other" "other"
[2,] "other" "maybe" "other" "maybe"
[3,] "other" "maybe" "maybe" "maybe"
[4,] "maybe" "maybe" "maybe" "maybe"
[5,] "other" "maybe" "maybe" "other"
[6,] "maybe" "maybe" "maybe" "maybe"
[7,] "maybe" "other" "other" "maybe"
[8,] "maybe" "maybe" "maybe" "other"
```